# Best way to have lading page and dashboard with absolutely different styles?

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I have the Nextsj static lading website with custom tailwind configs. Now I'm adding a dashboard into the same project, and faced an issue that with nextJs there is no way to add different tailwind configs for different pages.

**Question What is the best way to handle that?**

I see only one way:

Have two different nextjs projects, but this way much more complex project hosting, need by nginx tell /dashboard hosted by this app, / - hosted by this one, which I really do not want to do.

Comment: Why do you need two different TailwindCSS configs? What's the problem of using a single config even if the styles are different for each page?

Comment: @juliomalves I bought two different themes, and I do not really want to mess up with settings.